# Representing files and lines in a file in model view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, viewmodel

I am trying to come up with a model design to solve the follwoing problem: 
I have files (plain text and xml) which I want to be able to represrnt them in a view in ASP.NET, also, I would need to detect certain words in lines and keep track of them. So, we can imagine I have the following

```
CFile: List<Message> CertainMessages
```

My question is, how do I represents the lines in the file? should I make another class representing a line, and send 700+ lines to the view in my application?

Comment: What does CFile mean? What does List CertainMessages mean? Did you lose some formatting because you didn't mark the section as code?
You say that you want to "represent" the files in a view? What does that mean? Do you want to show them verbatim, allow editing or just show a list of file names?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 700+ lines then I suspect you might want to consider your interface a little in terms of readability.

It might pay to have next and previous buttons and there are buckets of samples for those things.

There's no real issue with having a list of 700+ items so long as each item is small.

For me I'd consider the user and maybe allow for next/previous and perhaps a filter to chop 700+ down to a serviceable 70 lines maybe.